# Using a single ContentProviderClient during a Fragment's lifecycle

Tags: android, android-contentprovider, android-contentresolver

In my application, I have code like that:

```
class MyFragment extends Fragment {
    ContentProviderClient client;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       ...
       client = getActivity().getContentResolver().acquireContentProviderClient("SOME_AUTHORITY");
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        client.release();
        ...
    }
}
```

It seems to work fine, but I am a bit concerned if it is okay to leave the `client` unreleased during all the Fragment's lifecycle? I wasn't really able to find anything indicating if it is a good or a bad practice.

Comment: http://selvin.pl/cpcif.jpg ... seriously, why?, why you need a CPC in fragment?

Comment: @Selvin well, I need to access my content provider in the fragment. I could do it either by using the ContentResolver, or by using the ContentResolverClient.

Comment: `ContentProviderClient` is for a "special" purposes (like syncing, etc). For accessing the data from CP methods of `ContentResolver` should be enough...

Comment: @Selvin syncing? Could you explain a bit deeper? I've always though that `ContentProiderClient` is basically `ContentResolver` with the fixed authority (so no overhead for directing the query to the right `ContentProvider`).

Comment: i'm not sure(i didn't dig the android source so much) but fx: `ContentResolver.query` internaly gets the ContentProiderClient connected with the uri, do the `query`on CPC and release it, then returns the result cursor to you so you don't have to be worry about releasing CPC ... as you are not doing CR.query/insert/update/delete in a fragment many times you should not be worry about performance... but in some sync adapter it will be better to "cache" the CPC instance by yourself (as asking OS to get underlaying CPC for uri could be expensive)edit: i just read your whole comment (you write same)

Comment: anyway, by syncing i meant: call some webservice to get data and then feed the contentprovider with it using insert/update and eventually delete ... so there could be a lots of rows => a lots of calls to those functions ... using CPC directly in fragment IMHO is premature optimization(aka root of all evil)

Answer (score 0):

You will want to cleanup all resources. release() should be called to let android know that the content provider is not needed and resources can be cleaned up. Also note, dont call release() unless you are done using the data that it has returned.

Check out the ContentProviderClient javadocs for more information.

Comment: Yeah,I know I should call release *at some point* (and I do that in `onDestroy`). However, I am not sure if it is okay keep the client open during the whole fragment lifecycle. You know, like a Cursor: you could open one in onCreate and close it in onDestroy, however, it is a bad pattern and one should localize open DB/IO connections.